# Django: Paginator returns all the data from db, and ordering is not working

Tags: django

I have this ListView and i am trying to get only 12 cars from my db, and order them by price, i have 20 entries in my db and in the buttons of pagination it shows 6 buttons, aka 6 pages, so it is returning all possible data from db, at this point I am lost and can't find the bug, any help would be very much appreciated for both, pagination and ordering.

```py
class CardListView(ListView):
    model = Car
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'cars'
    ordering = ['-price']
    paginate_by = 5
    limit = 12

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        paginator = context['paginator']
        page_numbers_range = 10 
        max_index = len(paginator.page_range)

        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        current_page = int(page) if page else 1

        start_index = int((current_page - 1) / page_numbers_range) * page_numbers_range
        end_index = start_index + page_numbers_range
        if end_index >= max_index:
            end_index = max_index

        page_range = paginator.page_range[start_index:end_index]
        cars = Car.objects.all()[:self.limit]
        car_types = CarCategory.objects.all()

        context['cars'] = cars

        context['car_types'] = car_types
        context['page_range'] = page_range
        return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to do the pagination logic by yourself, you only should implement in the `get_context_data` the *additional* elements you want to pass to the template. The pagination logic is handled by the [**`ListView`** itself](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.list/ListView/#paginate_queryset). If you want to limit the queryset, you should do that in the [**`get_queryset(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) function:

```
class CardListView(ListView):
    model = Car
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'cars'
    ordering = ['-price']
    paginate_by = 5
    limit = 12

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset()[:self.limit]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()  # with paginated queryset
        context['car_types'] = car_types = CarCategory.objects.all()
        return context
```

The original `ListView` implementation will call the `get_queryset`, and then pass it to the proper paginator. By using `super()` we furthermore do not need to care about the `ordering`, etc. These are all handled by the `ListView` itself.